# why std::map throws an exception?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dictionary, g++

I run this code using both gpp and microsoft compiler but in both case I'v got an exception
but I can't understand why!
this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<int,int> fib;

int fibo(int i)
{
    if (!fib.count(i))
    {
        fib.insert(pair<int, int>(i,fibo(i-1)+fibo(i-2)));
    }

    return fib[i];
}

int r(int i)
{
    if(i<3)
    {
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
        return fibo(i)+r(i-2);
    }
}

int main()
{


    fib.insert(pair<int, int>(0,1));
    fib.insert(pair<int, int>(1,1));

    int a,b,n;
    cin>>a>>b;

    n=b-a;

    int fiba=fibo(a);
    int fibaa=fibo(a-1);

    cout << (r(n+1)*fiba)+(r(n)*fibaa);

    return 0;
}
```

can anyone help me?

I debugged this code and I found that `fib.insert(pair<int, int>(i,fibo(i-1)+fibo(i-2)));` doesn't work.

Comment: What is the exception and where?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: the input was 1000000 and 2000000

Comment: @PaulManta: with that inputs, I'v got exception

Comment: @Fox32: VC++ 2010 doesn't show it!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Your code isn't designed to scale anywhere near that far. Try sensible inputs and you may get sensible output. (Or switch to an iterative algorithm rather than a recursive one.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It was from a contest and the inputs can bet up to 1000000000 and it is sensible  with this problem!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: what about any hint, e.g. backtrace or anything else?

Comment: @ezdazuzena: I didn't understand what did you say!

Comment: @ahmadali No, 1000000000 levels of recursion is not sensible.

Comment: Also, memory requirements are off the chart to maintain that map if you start inputting 1 000 000 000, you will have 2x4 bytes in ints per number alone thats 8GB, not to mention that you will overflow a 32-bit signed int in no time (47th number i would think).

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee If you need to handle numbers that large, you need to throw this code away and start over using a design that scales. Keeping everything you've computed in a map and all your context on the stack is not scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got Stack Overflow exception when I ran your code, obviously because of too deep recursion.
You should either increase stack size (but you can later choose to input a larger number and get the same exception again), or convert this algorithm into a non-recursive one (for example see this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/109443/Fibonacci-Recursive-and-Non-Recursive-C)

Comment: But I want Fibonacci with dynamic programming algorithm!

Comment: Then look for compiler-specific way to increase stack size AND catch stack overflow exception to provide user with meaningful message. E.g. for Visual C++ default stack size is only 1Mb (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks(v=vs.71).aspx). For your numbers I'd suggest to start with few hundred megabytes (as you want to have 2 mln calls in stack)

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: This problem can also be solved in a loop, instead of using recursion.  Then your call stack size is of no concern.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to input some negative numbers? You don't do any check on the inputs you pass to your program, and in

```
return fib[i];
```

you will receive an error if you try to access non-existent locations.

Comment: I edit my code and add some negative numbers checking but I didn't see any change in exceptions!